# How to force Windows Sign-In in a Desktop Bridge Application

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I have a Desktop Bridge in the Store, It has in-app purchases.

I have found that when an user has installed windows and has choose to Skip the credential part of the installing, they can download successfully our app from the MS Store.

But when the App is open and tries to communicate with the Windows Store to validate the license, it gets an error 0x80070525 saying that te account is invalid.

How can I force the display of the Microsoft Sign-In window in that scenarios?

Thanks

Comment: We're not able to force user to sign in Windows credential part through your app. Is the app account the same as the account in Store when they download your app?

Comment: Thanks! I did the test myself, I had to format a PC in the final phase of the windows 10 installation, when it asks to associate an email account, I clicked skip, so the Windows OS remained 'unsigned'. Then I download my own app from the Store, and when I ran it the big 0x80070525 Account Invalid appeared, it would be nice if after catching that error we can present the user the Microsoft Sign-In Windows.  (I really appreciate your time for answering this question)

Comment: Hi Felice - what API exactly are you calling that is giving you this error?